# Webpart always overlaps the footer in SPS2013?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, overlay, footer

I`ve tried checking the CSS, but cant find the reason for why Webpart overlaps the Footer in SPS2013. Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? Try describing by putting your code or screenshot.

Comment: Footwr is placed at the bottom. However, webpart placed at the bottom above the footer. While scrolling data it appear above the footer. Ideally knce the scroll is complete then atcthe end of the page u shud see the footer.

Answer (score 0):

This is some where fault in your custom css, check whether you have used any floats or position absolute